# MonoDroid package cannot be created

Tags: visual-studio-2012, xamarin.android, apk

I have been using MonoDroid in Visual Studio 2012 to create an Android app and everything works fine. I can publish the app to my phone and everything works fine (both debug and release builds). However, when I try to have MonoDroid create a **.apk** file I get the following error: 
`System.Exception: The "ResolveAssemblies" task's outputs could not be retrieved from the "ResolvedAssemblies" parameter. Parameter "includeEscaped" cannot have zero length.`

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turns out that Xamarin themselves believe I should do it manually. Guess this is not a high priority.

Comment: The problem apparently was quite stupid. Something was wrong with the generated key. After re-generating the key everything works fine.